# How to define button background at one place and used around the whole app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

I would like all the buttons of my android application use the **same background image**, that's all buttons have attribute:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_btn_bg"
```

Is there any way to define this in **one place** and take effect in the whole application's buttons? (instead of define the background on each button component)

I think define inside ***theme.xml*** could be a solution, but I do not know how to do it ? Could some one give me some hints?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Android styles, you reference the preset attributes of R.attr. Here, you want to to reference android:buttonStyle. You can try this :

```
<style name="ApplicationStyle" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/yourButton</item>
</style>
```

Also look in this [Themes and Styles](http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-themes-and-styles-in-android.html)

Answer (score 6):

Define styles.xml with the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="buttonStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_button</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And use the same style for any button within your application as:

```
<Button 
    android:text="Test Button" 
    android:id="@+id/btnTest" 
    style="@style/buttonStyle">
</Button>
```