# How to apply a res/color/xml style to a button created dynamically

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an xml file, res/color/btn_black that allows me to apply a gradient look to buttons.

I can use it in a layout.xml successfully by calling:

```
<Button
    android:background="@color/btn_black"
/>
```

Elsewhere, I am creating buttons dynamically in Java, and I want to apply the same style. When I try this using:

```
myButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.btn_black));
```

I get this error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
  File res/color/btn_black.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f040001
```

This seems to be the correct method from other questions I've found answered here, but it isn't working for me. What am I doing wrong?

edit: This is the file btn_black.xml for reference

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#343434" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#171717" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#343434"
            android:endColor="#171717"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#171717" />
        <corners
            android:radius="4dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: and XML for color/btn_black is what?

Comment: do have a file named btn_black.xml or what?

Comment: added btn_black.xml above.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a color in your colors.xml defined in wrong way. Your colors.xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="btn_black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

As I see, you have defined res/color/btn_black.xml, what is wrong. You need to create colors.xml file in /res/values/ directory.

If you have a gradient xml-file, then you need to put it in /res/drawable/ folder and call myButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_black)) method.

Comment: see additional xml above. it's not just a color, it's a style. It works perfectly fine in an xml layout, I just need to know how to apply it in Java.

Comment: to make it as a style, define a style for your button in /res/values/styles.xml and a gradient in /res/drawable/my_gradient.xml which you can add to your style with  <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_gradient</item>

Comment: you can check how to make a style for button in this discusion:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608170/how-to-define-button-background-at-one-place-and-used-around-the-whole-app

Comment: how to make a selector drawable, you can read in this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692642/android-customized-button-changing-text-color

Comment: Does it matter which drawable folder I put it in, (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi etc.)? Does there need to be a copy in each drawable folder?

Comment: Every folder depends on different device density. You can check this to read more about it:http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html. If you need only gradient you can just make res/drawable folder and put it there.

Comment: Placed the xml in res/drawable and tried applying it with 
myButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_black));
this tells me "Call requires API level 16 (current min is 8): android.widget.Button#setBackground"
setBackgroundDrawable is deprecated.
setBackgroundColor and setBackgroundResource do not work with drawable resources.
Any more ideas?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947603/setbackground-vs-setbackgrounddrawable-android, you can use something like this, and  you need to set buildTarget api 16 and min build to 7 or something similar. And please accept this as a best answer if this helped you.

Comment: I just taught myself to draw the button completely in java and gave up on trying to apply the existing xml. Moved on with my life. :) Thanks for your efforts along the way.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best solution is to define a layout for the button with a specific style.
Then you can inflate the button with the layout you've created.

See this question for specific help [android set style in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code)

So in your case you can use your xml file with the defined layout and inflate the button created programmatically

Comment: This was partially helpful. I changed my code to 
    Button myButton = new Button(EventsActivity.this, null, R.color.btn_black);

It no longer crashes, but the button does not display. Just the text. (Not even the default gray button is visibly now.)