# Custom Button style is applying partially

Tags: android, xml, button, android-styles

Created custom style for button when apply the style for button it is partially. Here is the style code snippet.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<application android:theme="@style:AppTheme">
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/back_button_style</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/back_button_style</item>
</style>

<style name="back_button_style" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="background">@drawable/back_button_shape</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">72dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">72dp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item> //sans-serif nothing but robot regular
</style>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="continue"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
```

After applying the style only the text color changes to white since i given the text color as white in style but other credentials are not applied background, before applying the button text color was black.
**So I not getting why it is partially applying the style.**

I tried like this also but it is not working

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="continue"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" 
    android:theme="@style/back_button_style/>
```

I am not getting what and where is the bug in the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create custom button in Android using XML Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507351/how-to-create-custom-button-in-android-using-xml-styles)

Comment: try `style="@style/back_button_style"` instead of `android:theme="@style/back_button_style"`

Comment: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Comment: style="@style/back_button_style", yaa I tried like this also but it is applying partially means only text color and margins are applied, but background and height is not applying, I checked separately by applying background on button it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rectify  <kbd>Button</kbd>  [**`android:theme`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html) section .

**Don't**

```
 android:theme="@style/back_button_style
```

**Do**

```
style="@style/back_button_style"
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`** .

Comment: I tried like this also but it is applying partially means only text color and margins are applied, but background and height is not applying, I checked separately by applying background on button it works

Comment: @ArchanaSM `android:background`

Comment: @ArchanaSM remove `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608323/3395198

Comment: @ArchanaSM Ji Glad to hear . Happy coding